# Surprisingly persistent local variable

Tags: auctex, debugging, variables, local-variables, revert-buffer

A local variable keeps coming back, and I know not whence.
In a certain buffer,
`TeX-command-extra-options` is `"--synctex=1"`, even after I have removed
this from my `init.el` and restarted Emacs.
I tried setting it to something else by adding

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "--output-directory=out/"
%%% End:
```

to the end of the file.  But, if I save and revert, the old value
persists.  If I `setq` the variable manually, and revert the file, the
old value comes back.  This doesn't happen with `emacs -Q`, but I was
hoping someone might know what is going on.  I suspect that AUCTeX is
somehow responsible.

---

Alternative question: how might I debug this?  It seems to me that, when
I revert, the variable is first set according to my specification, and
then reset by something or other.

Comment: Is `TeX-command-extra-options` a user option? If so, have you customized it, so it gets set automatically in your init file or your `custom-file`?

Comment: @Drew, no, I don't load the custom-file.

Comment: OK, for some reason there is a directory called auto/ containing code that is run automatically.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. You can accept your own answer. (An accepted answer improves the usefulness to others of a Q & A.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this, I had enabled TeX-auto-save, which saves settings to an auto/ directory and loads them when a file is revisited.

https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html